# Angular performance issues with large data sets and prime ng datagrid

Tags: angular, primeng

We've built an angular (V4.1) application with primeNG components mostly data table
The application was designed for small clients and we had no issues even with 2K-3K table rows being fetched completely
filtering worked with spreadSheet like performance

Today we installed the app with big client, his data is around 30K lines per table

app is not performing well, its slow and many times the browser just freezes.
What course of action is advisable?
We love the fact that we can bring all the data at one go from the server and user can filter it without further requests, but is there a hard limit that above it its a bad idea?
what other optimization techniques should i look for?

Comment: try using paginator. At a time it will display limited rows divided into pages, if you have 30k lines , then dividing table in 1000 pages will display only 30 rows at a time.

Comment: Hi, we have a paginator ,but the paginator itself is just dividing the table to many pages, its still a lot of data

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into implementing a [lazy](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/lazy) datable? From their docs about it

> "Lazy mode is handy to deal with large datasets, instead of loading the entire data, small chunks of data is loaded by invoking onLazyLoad callback everytime paging, sorting and filtering happens."

Comment: Thanks for the direction ill probably take this course, but their documentation seems quite sparse i didn't understand what happens when user filters whose responsibility it is to search the entire data, i suppose server

Comment: I haven't used their lazy loading personally so I won't be much help to you there.